# Этимология слова «Угрешский»

Tags: этимология

Какова этимология слова «Угрешский»?

Answer (score 1):

Слово «угреша», представляющее собой форму глагола «угреть» (буквальный перевод «угрели»), отражало настроение князя Дмитрия Донского в момент явления иконы, и, по преданию, он нарек место, точнее урочище, Угрешей.

Явление образа Николая Чудотворца накануне Куликовской битвы укрепило дух князя, придало ему уверенности в победе над Мамаем.

«Сие вся угреша сердце мое!» (Это все согрело мое сердце!)

https://history.wikireading.ru/350285

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о Николо-Угрешском монастыре (Угрешской обители), то его название связано с названием реки Угреша, этимология которого неизвестна.

Вероятно, этот гидроним балтийского или угро-финского происхождения, как и большинство гидронимов московской зоны.

За подробностями обратимся к материалу "Древнее название Угреша" (Е. Н. Егоровой)

> Вот что пишет известный специалист по топонимике Е.М. Поспелов:
> «Название урочища обычно связывают с рекой Угреша. Возможность былого
> существования этой речки косвенно подтверждается наличием гидронимов
> Угра, Угричка и Угреша в верховье бассейна Оки; Угриня в бассейне
> Западного Буга, Угр в бассейне Западной Двины, Ugra в Литве.
> Размещение этих гидронимов свидетельствует о вероятности их
> балтийского происхождения»

https://proza.ru/2008/08/28/16

По другой версии:

> Угреша — это трансформировавшееся с течением времени
> финно-угорское выражение «унгур ша», что означает «луговая река».
> Великолепные заливные луга в нашей местности действительно были, что
> подтверждает и предание об основании Николо-Угрешского монастыря, где
> говорится, что стан Дмитрия Донского был на месте, поросшем густыми
> травами.

там же.

Там же излагавется и широко распространенная "народная версия", связывающая название с фразой, якобы произнесенной Дмитрием Донским, "Сие вся угреша сердце мое!". Версия эта крайне сомнительна, ибо по данным автора мало того, что вся история посещения Донским тех мест базируется на неаттрибутированном источнике, хранящемся в библиотеке монастыря, так еще и самой фразы в нем нет.

От себя добавлю, что такая форма "угреша" здесь сомнительна еще и с точки зрения грамматики.